# SQLiteException no such column (code 1)?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I keep getting an error:

**SQLiteException: no such column: name (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, date, amount, item FROM items_table ORDER BY name**

every time I try entering an activity, it crashes and I'm not sure how to go about fixing it. I've tried many options suggested by other users in this forum however to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is my **Logcat**:

It seems to be pointing towards another activity as well called "T_Entertainment"

Here is the **T_Entertainment.class**

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    initList();
    prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(prefListener);

    //newEntry = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_entry);
    //newEntry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    //@Override
    //public void onClick(View v) {
    //startActivity(new Intent(T_Entertainment.this, NewEntry.class));
    //}
}
//}

private void initList(){
    if (model != null){
        stopManagingCursor(model);
        model.close();
    }
    model = helper.getAll(prefs.getString("sort_order", "name"));
    startManagingCursor(model);
    adapter = new ItemAdapter(model);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and here is my **Helper.class**

```
class Helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mymanager.db";
private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 2;

public Helper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // Will be called once when the database is not created
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE items_table (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + "date TEXT, amount TEXT, item TEXT);");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    //Will not be called until 2nd scheme i.e. when SCHEME_VERSION
    //increases

}

/*Read all records from items_table */
public Cursor getAll(String orderBy) {
    return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery (
            "SELECT _id, date, amount, item FROM items_table ORDER BY " + orderBy, null));
}

/* Read a record from items_table by ID provided */
public Cursor getById(String id) {
    String[] args = { id };

    return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, date, amount, item FROM items_table WHERE _ID=?", args));
}

/* Write a record into items_table */
public void insert(String date, String amount, String item) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put("date", date);
    cv.put("amount", amount);
    cv.put("item", item);

    getWritableDatabase().insert("items_table", "name", cv);
}

public void update(String id, String date, String amount, String item) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    String[] args = { id };
    cv.put("date", date);
    cv.put("amount", amount);
    cv.put("item", item);

    getWritableDatabase().update("items_table", cv, "_ID=?", args);
}

public String getID(Cursor c) {
    return (c.getString(0));
}

public String getDate(Cursor c) {
    return (c.getString(1));
}

public String getAmount(Cursor c) {
    return (c.getString(2));
}

public String getItem(Cursor c) {
    return (c.getString(3));
}

}
```

Comment: `db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE items_table (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + "date TEXT, amount TEXT, item TEXT);");` Where in this instruction is the column named **name**? I can't see it.

Comment: **"This is my Logcat:"** : Where is it? You haven't posted anything.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are updating your database from previous version to new where you have added one column.
Try to delete old application from device and install again, it shouldn't be issue anymore.